# Extract complete login settings

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2017, sql-scripts

I am using SQL Server 2017. I have created a login with mapping and various roles.

How can I get the create script of the complete login?

The script must contain all mapping and role information.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SSMS.

1. Right-click database name where your user is located.
2. Tasks->Generate Scripts
3. In the pop-up window go to "Choose Objects" tab.
   [image]
4. Select "Select specific database objects", then select the user you need. Click "Next"
5. On the next screen click "Advanced" button and set "Script Logins" to true. Click "OK" button
   [image]
6. Select preferred script output options and click "Finish" button.

Note: this will script all logins.
Note 2: Images produced using SSMS 2014